# Python: Convertir lista de diccionarios en archivo csv. ¿Cómo eliminar las filas vacías?

Tags: python, csv

Estoy tratando de convertir una lista de diccionarios con las mismas claves en un archivo csv , esta lista de diccionarios esta en la variable root.resultados. El código publicado se ejecuta bien, pero tiene dos comportamientos indeseados, que se ven al abrir el rachivo:

1. El archivo contiene algunas filas que quedan vacías porque no tienen valores. ¿Cómo puedo eliminar o evitar que el archivo quede con filas vacías?
2. Tiene que ver con la codificación. Traté de codificarlo a  utf-8 para que no salgan errores pero al ver el string en excel los elementos aparecen encerrados entre b''. ¿Cómo se puede evitar que los elementos queden encerrados así?

El código que llevo es el siguiente:

```
    data_csv = []
    data_csv.append([])
    for res in root.resultados:
        for key in res.keys():
            data_csv[0] += [str(key).encode("utf-8")]
        break
    for index, res in enumerate(root.resultados):
        data_csv.append([])
        for valor in res.values():
            data_csv[index + 1] += [str(valor).encode("utf-8")]

    with open(self.file_name_var.get()+".csv", "w") as archivo:
        escritor = csv.writer(archivo)
        try:
            for row in data_csv:
                if row or any(row) or any(field.strip() for field in row):
                    escritor.writerow(row)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empezare por la segunda parte de la pregunta. Lo que coloca las b'' es el `encode("utf-8")` al momento de volver el las claves y los valores a cadena. Si no se desean las b'' hay que dejar solo el `str()`

Así en el bucle que obtiene el encabezado del archivo:

```
data_csv[0] += [str(key)]
```

Y así en el bucle que obtiene los valores de cada diccionario

```
data_csv[index + 1] += [str(valor)]
```

En la primera parte se crea el encabezado del archivo, pero en el código que se publica con la pregunta se están repitiendo las claves en la primera línea del archivo por cada diccionario que se desea convertir en fila convertir en fila, lo cual no creo que sea lo que se quiera. Para generar las etiquetas de encabezado, se debe recorrer solo las claves de un diccionario, en este caso el primero (ya que se indica que todos tienen las mismas claves)

```
data_csv.append([])
#Obtener el encabezado
for key in root.resultados[0].keys() :
   data_csv[0] += [str(key)]
```

Para evitar que las lineas vacias (diccionarios cuyos valores son todos vacios) lleguen al archivo, hay que cambiar la logica del `if` en la parte que escribe el contenido en el archivo por una sucesion de `and` así:

```
if row and any(row) and any(field.strip() for field in row):
    escritor.writerow(row)
```